# Update query needed based on the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need a stored procedure which will update the error message column on the table based on the condition, if dob is null or greater than current date then error message column should be updated as 'invalid dob' and also based on the id it has to be updated, if the dob is lesser than current date and it is not null, then the error message column should not be updated. I need a update statement for this query, i tried it but it update all the columns without checking the condition. so please provide the solution for this query,Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data, expected output and whatever you have tried?

Comment: update e  set errormsg='invalid dob' from emp e where  eid = eid and
 exists (select 'x' from emp where dob>getdate() or dob is  null)

Comment: Please update in the Original Post. Also post the expected output.

Comment: selva, but the above query update all the columns.

Comment: Why do you have an error message column in your table? How would you handle multiple errors? This seems like a constraint to me.

Comment: @SeanLange because there is an error message report for this report that error message field values are used.

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement but it is really simple.

```
update SomeTable
set ErrorMessage = 'Invalid DOB'
where DOB is null
or DOB > getdate()
```

Comment: if i use the condition eid = eid , then it will update all the columns without checking the condition, why it is happening ?

Comment: Why would you include that predicate? That is like saying 1 = 1. ALL rows meet that criteria. Unless you want all rows to be updated, use the where clause to only allow the rows you want updated to be updated.

Comment: This code is set based. It will update all the relevant rows in a single pass with no looping or cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
create table TestEmployee (ID int, DOB DateTime, ErMsg varchar(20))
insert into TestEmployee (ID,DOB)
values (1, '10/02/2013'),
(2, null),
(3, '1/1/2016')

UPDATE TestEmployee SET ErMsg = 'Invalid DOB'
WHERE ID = @ID AND --This should based on your condition
DOB > GETDATE () OR DOB IS NULL

SELECT * FROM TestEmployee
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/845f8/1)

Comment: i inserted the value to that table, using loop condition, so instead of using @id, can i define something like id = id , directly ?

Comment: Please post your entire SP here.

Comment: @Ram why are you using a loop for an update like this?